# "504 Timeout while reading response from Server" after 60 seconds

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, timeout, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have a Spring boot web application deployed in AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I have an API that takes longer than 60 seconds to respond. I am getting "504 Timeout while reading response from Server" error after exactly 60 seconds of API request.

I have tried increasing the "Idle timeout" time to 120 seconds in the Elastic Load Balancer settings as shown in figure.
 This did not help.
[image: Idle Time]

I have also tried increasing the timeouts in nginx configuration. My **nginx.config** file is as show below

```
proxy_connect_timeout     600s;
proxy_send_timeout        600s;
proxy_read_timeout        600s;
send_timeout              600s;
```

This did not help as well.

When I reduce the time to less than 60 seconds in nginx configuration, errors are shown in **/var/log/nginx/error.log** file. However, if I increase the timeout to more than 60 seconds, no error is shown in the log file but still I'm getting "504 Timeout while reading response from Server".

Is there a way to increase the API response timeout to more than 60 seconds?

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Rokin, I'm facing the same issue, have you find any solution?

Comment: @DipeshShihora I opted for making the API asynchronous and updating the status of the API call in the database, and also sending a push notification to the frontend.

Comment: Same issue here. Tried those things you said. No luck